# Not getting private calendar events from Google

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I want to import all events from Google calendar. In my code I will authenticate user first. Once user is sign in successfully then I will call below API using GET request.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my Email/events?key=my App Key&fields=items(id,start,summary,status,end)
```

I am getting response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Once I change my calendar as a public it will give all events details, but if calendar is mark as a private then it’s giving above response.

Any one having idea how to get events details from private calendar?

Comment: Authenticating a user gives you access to their calendars.  It does not by default give them access to your calendar.  You will have to either set the calendar to public or use a service account authentication to write to it.

Comment: @DaImTo am authenticate user first. Should I have to append that token value in my request?

Comment: read my comment again.  Authenticating a user will give you access to "THEIR" calendars not "YOUR" calendar.    its not found because they don't have access.

Comment: @DaImTo I want to get event from my calendar not others calendar

Comment: Then you need to set your calendar to public or use a service account authentication and not oauth2 authentication  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from this Google Developer console

[LINK](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need add your access token to access your calendar information, if you use JavaScript library, you can take a look at these sample: 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication

I have implemented getCalendar using Angular JS + Ionic (using REST API)

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/
, but I am at work now, will send you later if you need it.

take a look at this example, you may understand how to attached yr request token to your request:

```
ionicExample.controller("DigitalOceanExample", function($scope, $http, $cordovaOauth) {

    $scope.digitalOceanLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.digitalOcean("CLIENT_ID_HERE", "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE").then(function(result) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", result.access_token);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    $scope.getDroplets = function() {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        $http.get("https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets")
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data.droplets));
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

});
```